# Are all diagonal cross sections of a closed form multivariable functions also closed form?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, closed-form

If we have some closed form multivariable function say 2-in, 1-out, the cross sections of the graph parallel to the $xz$ and $yz$ plane have equations that are inherently closed form.

But is the same true for the diagonal cross sections?  Say for example we have the function $f$:
$$f(x, y) = e^y\sin(x)$$
If we're given a $\vec{v}$ say, [1, 2] would the cross section of the graph of the plane formed by the $z$-axis and $\vec{v}$ inherently be closed form as $f$ is on the axes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, and it's easy to see why. Let's say we have some "nice" expression for $f(x,y)$. We want to consider the graph made by slicing the plane by some arbitrary vector, say $\mathbf{v}\in\mathbb{R}^2$. More precisely, what we are doing here is considering a the $z$ coordinate of a  path
$$\mathbf r(t)=\bigg(x(t)~,~y(t)~,~f\big(x(t),y(t)\big)\bigg)$$
Where $x(t),y(t)$ are just straight lines given by the components of $\mathbf{v}$:
$$x(t)=v_xt$$
$$y(t)=v_yt$$

So all we have to do is plug in these expressions to get our graph. In the case of $f(x,y)=\sin(x)e^y$ and $\mathbf{v}=(1,2)$ this is simply
$$\sin(t)e^{2t}$$
I suggest you check this graphically to confirm.